# Which is the best practice method for Angular JS customizing theme change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Method 1:

<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href=“cls-{{theme}}.css">
$scope.theme='normal';
$scope.themes = [{name:'red',url: 'red'},{ name:‘green’,url:‘green’}];

Method 2:
$scope.theme='red';
$scope.col=['red','green'];    
$scope.colorchange = function(a)
{
  $scope.theme=$scope.col[a];
}
<div class="cls-{{theme}}"></div>
```

Please suggest me which is best method for customizing theme change concept and give me explanation

Comment: you could put all the css in a file and then switch it based on user selection  https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-angularjs-and-nghref-to-grab-css-dynamically  and   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/load-css-theme-dynamically-on-user-selection-in-angularjs122

Comment: You said Method 1 is correct way..@user93

Comment: it is much easier to manage in case of large projects with lot of moving parts

Comment: but am used more than 4 or 5 css files means is it possible for "Method 1" @user93

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach:

1. Create a separate css file for every theme.

#### default.css

> ```
>   body.default{
>        .box{
>           background: #000;
>           color: #fff;
>        }
>   }
> ```

#### red.css

> ```
>   body.red{
>        .box{
>           background: #f00;
>           color: #fff;
>        }
>   }
> ```

#### green.css

> ```
>   body.red{
>        .box{
>           background: #0f0;
>           color: #fff;
>        }
>   }
> ```

2. Load all the themes(css files) in the main page. if possible load the css files asynchronously **except** default theme - [refer for async css](http://codepen.io/tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript)

   ```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="red.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="green.css">
   ```
3. When user change the theme just change the class name for the body tag, So idea is just change the root element class to reflect the selected theme.

   > ```
   > <body ng-class="{{theme_classname}}">
   > ```

   ```
   $scope.theme="default";
   $scope.colorChange = function(a)
   {
      $scope.theme_classname=$scope.col[a];
   }
   ```